# Error while compiling xv6 in Ubuntu(Makefile:124: recipe for target 'kernel' failed)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xv6

I just tried to complie xv6 in my Ubuntu 18.04.3 using `make qemu-nox`

It failed with the following error. Can you give me some information about this error?

> ld -m    elf_i386 -T kernel.ld -o kernel entry.o bio.o console.o exec.o file.o fs.o ide.o ioapic.o kalloc.o kbd.o lapic.o log.o main.o mp.o picirq.o pipe.o proc.o sleeplock.o spinlock.o string.o swtch.o syscall.o sysfile.o sysproc.o trapasm.o trap.o uart.o vectors.o vm.o  -b binary initcode entryother
>   trap.o: In function `tvinit':
>   /home/lee/OS-Homework/trap.c:23: undefined reference to`vectors'
>   /home/lee/OS-Homework/trap.c:24: undefined reference to `vectors'
>   Makefile:124: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
>   make: *** [kernel] Error 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking, `ld` complains about the lack of `vectors` array which is generated by rule `vectors.S`

```
vectors.S: vectors.pl
    perl vectors.pl > vectors.S
```

It seems that it that this rule is not generated...

To build `vector.S` just type `make vectors.S` before `make qemu-nox`, or even in one command:

```
make vectors.S qemu-nox
```